# Maximum sum of nodes in Left Child Right Sibling Tree such that no two are adjacent

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I've been working on LC-RS trees but can't build this algorithm. There are lots of information about other tree structers for this algorithm but apparently not a single one for LC-RS. How can I build the algorithm?

Here's for binary tree version.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-nodes-binary-tree-no-two-adjacent/